# Popupcalendar in Websphere Application Server 9 Tomahawk20

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, jsf-2.2, tomahawk, trinidad

I'm new to stackoverflow so please excuse any error.
I'm getting a PopupCalendar issue in my application using Tomahawk2, JSF 2, WAS9.

I've defined the ExtensionFilter - /faces/myExtensionResource/* and at runtime it should load in source /faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader -> calendar.HtmlCalendarRenderer while it is pointing to javax.faces.resource

The HTML is missing this:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/DERO_WEB/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader/15238805/calendar.HtmlCalendarRenderer/WH/theme.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/DERO_WEB/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader/15238805/calendar.HtmlCalendarRenderer/DB/theme.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/DERO_WEB/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader/15238805/prototype.PrototypeResourceLoader/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/DERO_WEB/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader/15238805/calendar.HtmlCalendarRenderer/date.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/DERO_WEB/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader/15238805/calendar.HtmlCalendarRenderer/popcalendar.js">
```

I have tried setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFiltersCompatibility=true in Web Container in WAS but that has not resolved the issue. I think this parameter setting is not required in WAS 9 but still I went ahead to see if it resolves anything.
Can anyone here help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'h:head' instead of 'head' did the trick for me and the calendar functionality started working as normal.